# Why bridge file can't find when compiled to static library?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, static-libraries

In my app, I use `cocoapods` to import some dynamic framework. Now I want to change dynamic framework to static library. So I add `s.static_framework = true` in `*.podspec`.Then I can compile this static library successfully. But when I import this static library to my app something goes wrong. The error likes below:
[image]

This static library contains `oc` and `swift` code. I want import a file coded by `swift` to this file coded by `oc`. And I have changed `use_frameworks!` to `use_modular_headers!` in `Podfile`.

Answer (score 0):

`s.static_framework = true` changes the library inside a framework from dynamic to static. The pod will still be integrated as a framework.

The option is only relevant for Podfiles that specify `use_frameworks!`.

If `use_modular_headers!` is in or `use_framework!` is not in the Podfile, `s.static_framework = true` has no effect. The pod will still be integrated as a static library.

Comment: Even if I delete `s.static_framework = true`,the error also exist. How can I solve it.